# Can not access private variable from child class in inherited method

Tags: php

```
class Configurable
{
    protected function configure(array $config): void
    {
        foreach ($config as $key => $value){
             if (property_exists($this, $key)){
                $this->{$key} = $value;
            }
        }
    }
}

class C extends Configurable
{
    private $abc;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->configure(['abc' => 5]);
    }
}

$c = new C();
```

This code gives me error `Cannot access private property C::$abc`

It is obvious when private variable in `parent` class but in this code the private variable is in child class and `property_exists` sees this variable. I can not find explanation in php docs.

My confusion is as follows.
Parent method is inherited in child. My assumption is that this method should have access to variable in child, but it does not have. `property_exists` knows about this property, but can not set it.

Answer (score 0):

use `protected`$abc` **visibility** cause of you're using parent method(configure()) in same class so in parent class abc variable can't be access cause of private.

```
class Configurable
{
    protected function configure(array $config): void
    {
        foreach ($config as $key => $value){
             if (property_exists($this, $key)){
                $this->{$key} = $value;
            }
        }
    }
}

class C extends Configurable
{
    protected $abc;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->configure(['abc' => 5]);
    }

    //this method is when you're trying to access $c->abc that'll return from here.
    public function __get($method)
    {
        return $this->$method;
    }
}

$c = new C();
echo $c->abc;
```

And if you want to use **Private** to define variable then you sould define configure() method in same class. and **__get** method is for when you're trying to access **protected** and **private** variable then this __get() function will called.

```
class Configurable
{
    protected function configure(array $config): void
    {
        foreach ($config as $key => $value){
             if (property_exists($this, $key)){
                $this->{$key} = $value;
            }
        }
    }
}

class C extends Configurable
{
    private $abc;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->configure(['abc' => 5]);
    }

    //method overriding
    protected function configure(array $config): void
    {
        foreach ($config as $key => $value){
             if (property_exists($this, $key)){
                $this->{$key} = $value;
            }
        }
    }

    public function __get($method)
    {
        return $this->$method;
    }
}

$c = new C();

echo $c->abc;
```

Comment: Your second example beats the purpose of inheritance and contradicts SOLID. I recommend @Vitaliy against adopting it. He should just use `protected` instead of `private`.

Comment: Agree with you @Aydin4ik but he's trying to access variable using private that's why I made second approach just only for him.